# Empty DataFrame in PySpark with Dynamic Schema and not using Pandas

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to create an empty Dataframe and the schema should match to an existing Pyspark Dataframe .I tried using Structtype manually .

Answer (score 1):

To create an empty dataframe call `spark.createDataFrame` with empty array and providing the schema object from the original dataframe:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 1)], ('foo', 'bar'))

df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- foo: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- bar: long (nullable = true)

df.show()
# +---+---+
# |foo|bar|
# +---+---+
# |  1|  1|
# +---+---+

empty_df = spark.createDataFrame([], df.schema)

empty_df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- foo: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- bar: long (nullable = true)

empty_df.show()
# +---+---+
# |foo|bar|
# +---+---+
# +---+---+
```